# MySQL/Mariadb per-record overhead?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, storage, innodb, overhead

what, if any, is the per-record disk overhead for mysql/mariadb? (i'm mostly interested in InnoDB, but any engine would interesting)

lets say you just have a

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

obviously this will use *at least* 8 bytes (BIGINT) per record, but will it use more than that per record?

Comment: I can't quite see the point of this question - if you need bigint then you need bigint..Is this about sizing your physical server? performance? or just an I'm curious question?

Comment: Nearly every table I have encountered does not need `BIGINT`; a 4-byte `INT UNSIGNED` is more than enough; an even smaller datatype usually suffices.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of overhead.

- Per 16KB block:  several pointers, flags, etc.
- Per row:  about 2 dozen bytes of links, transaction stuff, etc.  Even more, if a row is being touched by multiple transactions at the same time.
- Per column:  1- or 2-byte length and NULLness.  Yes even for that 8-byte BIGINT.
- PRIMARY KEY:  This is quite low because the PK is clustered with the data; it adds up to about 1% of the entire table.
- Secondary keys:  Each secondary key (`INDEX(...)`) contains the columns indicated, *plus* a copy of the PK column(s).  It is a separate BTree.  So, for this reason, there may be multiple copies of your BIGINT occupying disk space.
- InnoDB initially allocates in 16KB block chunks (data and each secondary index separately).  Later it pre-allocates in bigger chunks.  I think your sample table will use 16KB until you have several hundred rows in it.
- InnoDB does not release space back to the OS.  That is, if you insert a thousand rows, then the table will be expanded to several blocks.  Then, if you delete all the rows, the disk space won't shrink.

Aside from the indexes, that 8 bytes for the bigint, plus similar computations for other columns can be added up.  But then you must multiply by 2 to 3 to get the disk space needed for an InnoDB table.  (Of course, there are exceptions with less than 2x or more than 3x.)

I'll be happy to discuss other examples, but I cannot be very precise.